# Javascript button to mute background video

Tags: javascript

i have website with system, where i upload video. I can edit code only via CSS and JS.

I need some button, which mute the background video with music. Dont stop video, only mute music.

Can you help me?

Here is the page:
https://www.paddleboardy.cz/

I try this, but not working:

```
 <a onclick="document.getElementById('#videoWrapper').muted = true; return false">
 <img src="https://www.paddleboardy.cz/user/documents/upload/mute-icon.png"/>
</a>
```

THX

Answer (score 0):

```
 <a onclick="document.querySelector('#videoWrapper video').muted = true;>
```

Change your code to this, `document.getElementById` doesn't require a #, however you can use # for id in `document.querySelector`. `return false` is unnecessary. Furthermore, due to your HTML structure you have to target the video element in your videoWrapper, therefore `'#videoWrapper video'` is the correct selector.

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById` does not require a `#` to get the element. Also `#videoWrapper` is not the actual video element so you'll need to do something like this: `document.querySelector('#videoWrapper video').muted = true`.

Comment: I will need a little bit more information than that. Pasting the last line of code in the answer above is working in the devtools console.

Comment: You have the `a` tag inside a `script` tag so that's one reason the button is not showing. Also, I can only see your older code there that you should replace with the one in my answer.

Comment: sorry i dont understand, now i have:
   <script>
<a onclick="document.getElementById('#videoWrapper video').muted = true; return false">
    <img src="https://www.paddleboardy.cz/user/documents/upload/mute-icon.png"/>
</a>
</script>

Comment: replace `document.getElementById('#videoWrapper video').muted = true` with `document.querySelector('#videoWrapper video').muted = true` and remove the `script` tag around the link. `<script>` is used for JavaScript code and the `a` tag is an HTML element, so it won't work inside a `script` tag.